After transfer module in android studio I get "Cannot access script base class 'org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript'...."
I moved the module of my project to a subfolder, but the build.gradle of the transferred module does not work, it shows the error "Cannot access script base class 'org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies"
And the project is't building.
I fixed the dependencies in build.gradle and settings.gradle. May be someoe is knowing how to fix it or maybe I've did it wrong. Anyway I need some advice or guide? how to do it correctly

Maybe you could summarise your new project structure? Does running Gradle from the command line work?
